# Where is the source code - installed wordpress (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have installed the wordpress on google cloud platform through wizard provided by google itself.

I want to edit the files but Where is the source code - installed wordpress (solution provided by Google Click To Deploy)

I found already same question is pending

[How to access WordPress files on Google Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41341429/how-to-access-wordpress-files-on-google-cloud)

Comment: You can easily manage your resources with [Google's Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/)

Comment: Google's Cloud Shell is not showing any files inside my directory

Comment: You can install Wordpress manually. The installation takes about 5 minutes and is very easy to follow: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ssh into your app https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

in terminal...
cd .. (will go to $home)
cd .. (will go to root page)
cd var /www/html

all the files can be found at "/var/www/html"

Comment: Just type at once: cd ../../var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to edit your WordPress files.

Click on your VM instance SSH button, Then type

> sudo nano /var/www/html/wp-config.php

To view the aviable files use ls -la command
eg,

> ls -la /var/www/html/

If you need help you can check it out this two blog posts:

- [WordPress on Google Cloud: The Definitive Guide](https://www.siteyaar.com/google-cloud-wordpress/)
- [WordPress Multisite on Google Cloud: A to Z Installation Guide](https://www.siteyaar.com/google-cloud-wordpress-multisite/)