# Wordpress themes deployment using google cloud

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I'm really new to google cloud and I really like it. The issue is, I installed WordPress VM Instance on Google Cloud Platform - Computer Engine, but I am not sure how to paste my theme in the wp-content folder. I'm pretty sure it's not a convenient way to deploy WordPress theme but I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "my theme"? Do you mean a custom theme that you are developing?

Comment: Did you install the WP from the marketplace? Are you looking for an automated way to install your new theme, since you wouldn't like to manually do the zip upload method?

Comment: @jabbson I'll try doing it manually using GKE. Hopefully I can access it using Cloudshell.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes

Comment: So I installed wordpress manually using GKE but I can't find the source file of my Wordpress site. I tried going through every folder but couldn't find it. Here's a list of the files: cloud-pubsub      guestbook        hellonode            quickstart          wordpress-persistent-disks
cloudsql                    hello-app        LICENSE              README.md
CODEOWNERS                  hello-app-cdn    load-balancing       try-gke
CONTRIBUTING.md             hello-app-redis  migrating-node-pool  whereami
custom-metrics-autoscaling  hello-app-tls    network-policies     windows-multi-arch

Answer (score 0):

SSH into your [app](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance), in the terminal and try the following commands:

cd .. (will redirect to $home)

cd .. (will redirect to root page)

cd var/www/html

All the files can be found at "/var/www/html"
or
just type at once: cd ../../var/www/html

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186849/where-is-the-source-code-installed-wordpress-google-cloud-platform/43189282) for additional information.